# Have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other warning appearing in only ONE situation

Tags: java, android, generics, android-adapter

I am extending the abstract class RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
public static abstract class Adapter<VH extends ViewHolder> {
    public abstract VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position);

    // some more code
}
```

Into another abstract class:

```
public abstract class Adapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public abstract VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int position);

}
```

But when I do that, ONLY the `onBindViewHolder` method shows an error:

> 'onBindViewHolder(VH, int)' in 'com.leonardo.endlessrecycerviewwithsqlitepagination.adapter.ViewHolder' clashes with 'onBindViewHolder(VH, int)' in 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Why the same thing doesn't happend to the `onCreateViewHolder` method?

Another question is in this scenario:

```
public abstract class Adapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder.CustomViewHolder> {

    public abstract VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position);

    static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Why now BOTH methods display the error above?

Comment: did you mean:

public abstract class Adapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

Comment: If you changed ViewHolder for Adapter, yes, I noticed and changed it, but thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: no, i mean the type parameter you're putting into the class derivation signature, pass "VH" down into the extends part.

Comment: Ohh.. I see.. But i really mean: extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> NOT extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>. I got what you said now, but that's not what I want :\

Comment: I think that is what you want and that's exactly why you're getting the error.

The one method flags because return types / parameter types are different in regards to generics.  covariance and contravariance.

https://briangordon.github.io/2014/09/covariance-and-contravariance.html

Comment: But why ONLY ONE method displays the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130970/discussion-between-leonardosibela-and-john-newman).

Comment: Then that's the answer to my question.... "return types / parameter types are different in regards to generics". I wasn't aware of that. I'm reading the "Covariance and contravariance rules in Java" post, but if you could answer it, I would gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are not propagating your own abstract class' parameter down to the top of the chain; you are doing:

```
public abstract class Adapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

To make this less confusing, let's call Adapter's generic parameter VH2; then, we have:

```
public abstract class Adapter<VH2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

and

```
public static abstract class Adapter<VH extends ViewHolder>
```

So the methods inherited from RecyclerView.Adapter must have a VH type, not VH2! See the difference? In your abstract implementation, VH = RecyclerView.ViewHolder. So everywhere there was VH, you must now put RecyclerView.ViewHolder instead of VH2.

And why one of the methods 'work' and the other doesn't, you might ask?

Well, that's because of how OOP works. Observe that your VH2 is defined as extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder. So VH2 *is* RecyclerView.ViewHolder.

So if a parent method *returns* a VH, you can in your inheritance, *specify* what kind of VH it returns; in this case, VH2 is a VH, so you can safely do:

```
public abstract VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);
```

Take this example:

```
public abstract class Farm {
    Animal abstract getAnimal();
}

public class Abattoir extends Farm {
    @Override
    Pig getAnimal() { ... }
}
```

That's okay! Abattoir always returns an Animal, as Farm requires, because Pigs are animals!

Now let's think about the other method:

```
public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int position);
```

Here, the parent requires that the parameter be of type VH = ViewHolder. In this case, you cannot put something more specific in the child! The parent requests that every child knows how to handle every possible ViewHolder, not just those VH2 that extends ViewHolder. Here you can be more generic you want, but can't be more specific! For example:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    abstract void eat(Food f);
}

public class Pig extends Animal {
    @Override
    void eat(Carrot c) { ... }
}
```

This won't work! By extending Animal, you must comply to its requirements! Animal requires that every animal must have an eat method that can eat any food, not just carrots. Imagine I did this:

```
Animal a = new Pig();
// ...
a.eat(wheat); // ??
```

What would happen? So as you can see, with parameters you can be more generic, but can't be more specific. And with return types, you can be more specific, but not more generic. Because the parent contract requires you to receive A and return B. If you want to receive more than A, or return less than B, that's okay, it's your call. But you must receive at least A, and return at most B. That's how OOP works.

So your problem was just disguised in generics, but it's far broader ;)

Comment: I wasn't aware of this difference between return and parameter types, but makes total sense now that you explained. It turns out it's not related to Generics specifically, but OOP in general.